# spring data neo4j anonymous class support

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Does **Spring Data Neo4j** support persistence of anonymous classes? I managed to persist an object of an anonymous class, but when trying to create an index (by `@Indexed` annotation), there were problems - in SDN 2.3.4.RELEASE I couldn't get unique index to work, and in 3.0.0.RELEASE I got an error:

```
Error executing statement CREATE INDEX ON :``(`email`); nested exception is org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExecutionException: '' is not a valid token name. Only non-null, non-empty strings are allowed.
```

I have an abstract User class which is subclassed with Person and Company. But at the creation of fresh database I want to create one admin user, for which I decided (perhaps wrong) that creating distinct domain class is not necessary, so I created it as an anonymous class object. My user class looks similar to this:

```
@NodeEntity
public abstract class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GraphId
    Long id;
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String email;
    private String encPass;

    public abstract Type getType();

    // ...plus some more fields and getters/setters
}
```

Comment: Can you share more code of what you did? And why do you want to use an anonymous class as domain class? Doesn't really make sense to me?

Comment: Added some code and explanation, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that SDN can derive sensible meta-information from anonymous entities. You will have to handle them yourself with plain cypher statements.

What does the creation code for your admin-entity look like?

Comment: It's my admin creation code:
`public static User createAdmin() {
User admin = new User() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public Type getType() {return Type.ADMIN;}
public boolean isComplete() {return true;}
};
admin.setEmail("admin@freelance");
admin.setEncPass("???");
return admin;
}` (sorry for formatting, I think it's best I can do in a comment) But I think I'll simply end up with an Admin domain class :-)